# Change color of .btn-navbar in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to change the color of the responsive collapsed .btn-navbar in Bootstrap. It's normally black with the 3 horizontal lines, I just want the black to be a different color. If I alter .btn-inverse .btn-navbar:hover I get a strange effect but simply changing .btn-inverse .btn-navbar does nothing.

Comment: Please include some code or a simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your markup, styles js ect and update your question. so that we can try to help you.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use jsFiddle right now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xg443/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the order of your styles? If you try to change before the twitter bootstrap, the bootstrap will take precedence.

Comment: I have the 2 bootstrap CSS pages followed by my own styles page. Even trying to change it there wasn't fully working.

Comment: is there anyway that you can use jsfiddle to paste your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xg443/3/ - Try using background instead of background-color. Also, your last statements have double ## which isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the ## Jamie! I tried background and got the same result.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xg443/5/ - My bad, I forgot to hit update after I made a change. Look at this and you'll see the button is a different color.

Answer (score 0):

This changes the main background to red:

```
.nav {
background: #ff0000 !important;
}
```